# need help for windows phone 8 to communicat with arduino using NFC

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, arduino-uno

I'm implementing a project, in which i require to send a message(sequence of digits) over NFC to external NFC stacked over Arduino. i need to know, how will this be possible to receive the message from phone, and also arduino to send back response to windows phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that on the Arduino side, you are using some NFC shiled based on NXP's PN532.

WP8 supports two of NFC's three operating modes:

1. Peer-to-peer mode (using SNEP on top of LLCP on top of NFCIP-1)
2. Reader/writer mode (based on the NFC Forum's tag operation specifications)

As the PN532 supports all operating modes, it is up to you to choose between P2P and R/W mode.

So, these two scenarios would be possible:

1. WP8-P2P <-> PN532-P2P

   ```
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | WP8 app (registered to send/receive NDEF message to/from other NFC device) |
   |                                                                            |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                         SNEP                         |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                         LLCP                         |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                        NFCIP-1                       |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |                                                                            |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                         /\
                                         ||
                                         \/
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                                            |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                        NFCIP-1*                      |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                         LLCP*                        |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                         SNEP*                        |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |                                                                            |
   |                               Arduino + PN532                              |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```

   *) Needs to be configured/implemented (libraries may already be available).
2. WP8-R/W <-> PN532-HCE

   ```
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |      WP8 app (registered to write/read NDEF message to/from NFC tag)       |
   |                                                                            |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |   Reader/writer for NFC Forum Type 4 Tag operation   |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                    ISO/IEC 7816-4                    |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |           Reader/writer for ISO/IEC 14443            |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |                                                                            |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                         /\
                                         ||
                                         \/
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                                            |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |      Host card emulation mode for ISO/IEC 14443*     |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |                    ISO/IEC 7816-4*                   |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |          |            NFC Forum Type 4 Tag operation*           |          |
   |          +------------------------------------------------------+          |
   |                                                                            |
   |                               Arduino + PN532                              |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```

   *) Needs to be configured/implemented (libraries may already be available).

Comment: thanks for the advice. I further need help. I want to compare the message received from windows phone to PN532, with a particular data how can i used the data received for further processing.

Comment: @Roughtzy That seems to be a new question, so please post that as a new question including all necessary information (i.e. what you have tried so far and were you are stuck).

Comment: Never mind, i got it working. Still thanks for your information you provided.